# How does recursion work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have this method which switches the number digit 5 with 7.

```
def switch_digit(num)
   if num <= 0
     return 0
   end

  digit = num % 10

  if (digit == 5) 
    digit = 7
  end

  return switch_digit(num/10) * 10 + digit
end

switch_digit(5952)
```

Can someone explain why once the method hits the base case it doesn't return 0?

How does this recursive method actually work? Does it append the returned digit with the next digit?

Comment: Yes it does. You just need to be informed: add `puts 0` before `return 0`

Comment: If i do that it returns `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`

Comment: There is nothing special about recursion in Ruby. Calling `switch_digit(0)` returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

The base case returns 0, but the *overall* result is determined by the `return switch_digit(num/10) * 10 + digit`

Follow the code through with a smaller example e.g. `switch_digit(15)`:

```
num <= 0 # no
digit = num % 10 # 5
digit == 5 # yep, so swap it for a 7

return switch_digit(num/10) * 10 + 7
```

`num/10` is 1 so what does the recursive `switch_digit(1)` evaluate to?

```
num <= 0 # no
digit = num % 10 # 1
digit == 1 # so leave it unchanged
return switch_digit(num/10) * 10 + 1
```

`num/10` is 0 so **now** we hit the base case

```
switch_digit(15) == switch_digit(1) * 10 + 7
switch_digit(1) == switch_digit(0) * 10 + 1
switch_digit(0) == 0 # the base case
```

working back up, plugging in values from lower down results:

```
switch_digit(1) == 0 * 10 + 1  == 1
switch_digit(15) == 1 * 10 + 7 == 17
```

---

I'd also add that there's nothing specific to Ruby about how recursion is handled here. Any other descriptions of recursion, or classic example such as a [recursive factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_programs) should help you get a better understanding.

Comment: So, once it hits the base case going down it goes back up the stack using the value of the previous stack?

Comment: hitting the base case and then going back up the stack is spot on but I'd think of it as passing results back up the stack rather than using the value of the previous stack. I've updated the answer to clarify a bit so you can see how results from lower down the stack plug in to expressions higher up the stack to eventually result in the overall answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added a little change to your code, to be aware it's working.

Finally I also expected the value of the method was 0, but it is not.
The end is reached, but the returned value is not 0. **Why?**

```
def switch_digit(num, array)
  if num <= 0
    array << num
    p array
    puts "The end"
    return 0
  end
  digit = num % 10
  array << [digit, num]
  if (digit == 5) 
    digit = 7
  end
  return p switch_digit(num/10, array) * 10 + digit
end

p "returned value = " + switch_digit(123456789, Array.new).to_s
```

Which outputs:

```
#=> [[9, 123456789], [8, 12345678], [7, 1234567], [6, 123456], [5, 12345], [4, 1234], [3, 123], [2, 12], [1, 1], 0]
#=> The end
#=> 1
#=> 12
#=> 123
#=> 1234
#=> 12347
#=> 123476
#=> 1234767
#=> 12347678
#=> 123476789
#=> "returned value = 123476789"
```